# Regex to match the path before the resource from a URL

Tags: c#, regex, url

Just so everybody understand the vocabulary involved, the general structure of a URL is as follows:

```
  http   ://   www.a.com   /  path/to/resource.html  ?  query=value  #  fragment
{scheme} ://  {authority}  /         {path}          ?   {query}     #  {fragment}
```

The path consists of a path and a resource, in the case of `path/to/resource.html` the path is `path/to/` and the resource is `resource.html`.

**Poor, Nasty and Brutish:**
HTML, as it is found in the wild, can be [poor, nasty and brutish,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leviathan_%28book%29#Part_I:_Of_Man) though quite often far from short. In this poor, nasty and brutish world happen to live links, which in themselves can be poor, nasty and brutish, despite the fact that URLs are supposed to adhere to [the standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616). So with this in mind, I present you the problem...

**Problem:**

I'm trying to create a regex to remove the resource from a URL's path, which is necessary when there is a link within a web page that is a relative path. For example:

1. I visit `www.domain.com/path/to/page1.html`.
2. There is a relative link to `/page2.html`
3. Remove the `/page1.html` from the URL
4. Append `/page2.html` to `www.domain.com/path/to`

Result: in `www.domain.com/path/to/page2.html`

**I'm stuck on step 3!**

I've isolated the path and resource, but now I want to separate the two. The regex I tried to come up with looks like this: `\z([^\/]\.[^\/])`

In C# the same regex is: `"\\z([^/]\\.[^/])"`

Translated in English, the regex is supposed to mean: *match the end of the string which includes all characters separated by a dot as long as those characters are not slashes.*

I tried that regular expression, but currently it fails miserably. What is the proper query to achieve the said result.

Here are some sample cases:

/path/to/resource.html **=>** /path/to/ **and** resource.html
/pa.th/to/resource.html **=>** /pa.th/to/ **and** resource.html
/path/to/resource.html/ **=>** /path/to/resource.html/
/*I#$>/78zxdc.78&(!~ **=>** /*I#$>/ **and** 78zxdc.78&(!~

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your final sample is not a legal URI as it contains a number of characters which must be escaped.

Comment: Why not use [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)?

Comment: @Rob I know it's not a legal URI, but there is nothing stopping people from putting such links in their web pages. I still have to parse such links (although the Uri class takes care of most of this stuff).

Comment: @amit_g I already use the Uri class but it only provides a [PathAndQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery.aspx) (which is actually Path+Resource+Query), so I remove the query and I still have to remove the resource.

Comment: @Lirik, use [Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx), [Segments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments.aspx), [Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query.aspx) and [Fragment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.fragment.aspx)

Comment: @amit_g Host, Segment, Query and Fragment are all irrelevant to the Path. There is AbsolutPath (which I should use) and PathAndQuery (which I'm currently using), but both of them don't close the path with a slash when it doesn't have a resource so I have to look for something that resembles a resource.

Comment: @Lirik, I guess code is worth thousand words :) Check the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.domain.com/path/to/page1.html?query=value#fragment");

Console.WriteLine(uri.Scheme); // http
Console.WriteLine(uri.Host); // www.domain.com
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsolutePath); // /path/to/page1.html
Console.WriteLine(uri.PathAndQuery); // /path/to/page1.html?query=value
Console.WriteLine(uri.Query); // ?query=value
Console.WriteLine(uri.Fragment); // #fragment
Console.WriteLine(uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 1]); // page1.html

for (var i = 0 ; i < uri.Segments.Length ; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, uri.Segments[i]);
    /*
    Output
    0: /
    1: path/
    2: to/
    3: page1.html
    */
}
```

Comment: Gotcha! So to put your code in "1000 words": your suggestion is to look at the last segment and if it contains a dot, then I split the absolute path on the last slash '/' and use anything before it as the path. Looping through the segments and `Concat`ing strings might be a bit too slow.

Comment: It won't be much slower than the steps needed in RegEx unless you are going to process millions of path in short period of time. Also there is no need to concat. If the last segment is determined to be a resource, Replace(uri.AbsolutePath, uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length - 1], "") is the path you are looking for.

Comment: I am in fact trying to process millions of paths in a short period of time... thanks for the suggestion and clarification.

Comment: @Lirik, never done millions of paths processing so I won't know how much slower, if any, would it be to use Uri class vs RegEx. Suggest to do a benchmark both ways and see if there is a performance difference and if so how much. Needless to say, using a class like Uri (well tested my MS and others) would provide relatively easier, quicker and less brittle code when compared to writing a custom RegEx for something like Url. However, the performance gain may be worth spending time on building a custom solution. Let us know how it goes and if you have benchmark results, that would also be great.

Comment: I'm currently processing about 100k URLs per second with this solution, so unless somebody complains about the performance, then I'm not going to obsess over it too much.

Answer (score 2):

Does your regular expression engine support variable-length look-aheads?  If so, you can use that to look ahead (therefore excluding) the non-slash characters at the end:

```
.*/(?=[^/]*$)
```

Alternatively, use capturing groups and the path will be **group 1**, the resource **group 2**:

```
(.*/)([^/]*$)
```

A non-regex algorithm would be this:

1. Store `pos` of last slash
2. Substr from 0 with length of `pos+1`

**Note**:  I have purposely ignored `.`'s here.  What significance do they serve?  In HTML, if you have a path that does not end in a slash, relative paths will be **relative to last part's parent**.  So for the purposes of this discussion, a part with no dots is basically an extension-less resource.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine why you'd want to use regular expressions for this when the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class does almost all the work for you already. And to get the final part (i.e. separate the resource from the path), you can just use `String.LastIndexOf` and `String.Substring`. For example:

```
Uri myUri;
if (!Uri.TryCreate(linkString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out myUri))
{
    // some kind of error.
}
int pos = myUri.AbsolutePath.LastIndexOf('/');
++pos;
string resource = myUri.AbsolutePath.Substring(pos);
```

I have little doubt that you can do that stuff with a regular expression. I doubt, though that it's a win. As you said, the urls you find when you're crawling the Web can be pretty bad. My crawler spends considerable effort normalizing some really wild looking urls. I regularly run across things like `http://example.com/dir/subdir/subsubdir/../../dir///moretrash/resource.html`. And you wouldn't believe (or perhaps you would, if you're crawling the Web) the weird escaping that I see. The `Uri` class does a good job of parsing the url so that I can then normalize it. Unescaping is something that you just can't do with a regular expression.

My experience has been that the time to create the `Uri` instance is dwarfed by the time it takes to normalize urls: unescape, strip fragments and session identifiers, identify and avoid proxies and crawler traps, remove extraneous slashes and path navigation (i.e. `/./` and `/../`), etc. I just don't see where using a regular expression, even if it were faster than `Uri.TryCreate` would improve my run times. And I doubt seriously that it can do as good a job as `Uri.TryCreate` in parsing the urls that I find in the wild.

Comment: As far as I know System.Uri does not have a Path property (correct me if I'm wrong here), it only has a [PathAndQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery.aspx), which I'm currently using... I split the query out but I'm left with several types of paths, such as a path that does not end with a slash, `/path/to`, so your solution would consider the `/path/` as a path and `to` as a resource.

Comment: I think he means AbsolutePath (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx) but if you are going to do that, then you should just use the linkString with the LastIndexOf and Substring in the parsing instead of constructing a URI first.

Comment: @Brian, got it... AbsolutePath would probably be OK, I'm going to check if it actually puts a slash at the end of a path that does not contain a resource. If it does, then I should be set.

Comment: Ahh shoot! I mean AbsoluteUri (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri.aspx) not AbsolutePath...

Comment: @Brian, the absolute path is the closest thing to what I have right now, but it too doesn't close the path with a slash when there is no resource... so now I have to check for the last slash and then check for a dot after it, which might be done faster with a regex.

Comment: @Lirik: Sorry for the confusion, I meant `AbsolutePath`. I've corrected my example. And, yes, my solution would always take the last part as the resource. If you want to ensure that there's a period in there, you can use `IndexOf`, or you can write a regular expression that takes everything after the last slash in the `AbsolutePath` and makes sure there is a period in it.

Comment: @Brian: No, I meant `AbsolutePath`. I think you're still better off with `Uri`, though, because you have to handle stripping out the query and the fragment.

Comment: @Lirik & @Jim Mischel: The AbsolutePath can give you something different in some instances. It's a small gotcha, but one you should know about none the less. Taken from the MSDN: "Typically this is the path to the desired information on the server's file system, although it also can indicate the application or script the server must run to provide the information."

Answer (score 1):

To extract the resource portion of a URI, you could use:

```
^                  # matches start of str
.*                 # greedy match up to the last '/'
\/                 # literal '/'
(                  # start capture of resource part
   [^\/\?\#]*      # zero or more chars except '/', '?', and '#'
)                  # end capture
(?:                # start optional group - query part
  \?               # literal '?' for optional query
  .+?              # non-greedy match for any chars
)?                 # end of optional group
(?:                # start of optional group - fragment part
  \#               # literal '#' for optional fragment
  .+?              # non-greedy match for any chars
)?                 # end of optional group
$
```

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps you should split the string on '/' rather than stuck on coming up with a regex. also have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952653.aspx

Comment: I can't split the string on the '/' because a path can be `/path/to/resource.html` or just `/path/to`... if I split on the slash then it will consider `to` as a resource when it's actually part of the path. Of course I can check if the last item contains a '.', but I think a regex might be more efficient at this (I would have to test it).